# How to save an empty a field in database table mapped to double?

Tags: java, hibernate

In the Hibernate Layer,database column price is mapped with Double type. However due to the business logic, I have to handle empty field for the price. Not having a price and having 0.0 for price have two different meaning in the buiness logic.  How to handle this?

```
boolean day1 = true;
boolean day2 = true;
boolean day3 = true;
boolean day4 = true;
boolean day5 = true;
boolean day6 = true;
boolean day7 = true;
//double ogPrice = 10.99;


OrderGuideProduct orderGuideProduct = new OrderGuideProduct();

orderGuideProduct.setDay1(day1);
orderGuideProduct.setDay2(day2);
orderGuideProduct.setDay3(day3);
orderGuideProduct.setDay4(day4);
orderGuideProduct.setDay5(day5);
orderGuideProduct.setDay6(day6);
orderGuideProduct.setDay7(day7);

//  this is where I need to set the empty value
orderGuideProduct.setOgPrice();
```

Comment: Lookup the little known and rarely used SQL keyword known as "NULL".

Comment: Also floating-point is different from fixed-decimal. not everything with a decimal point is a floating point number.

Comment: Why are you using doubles? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a `BigDecimal` rather than a `double` in this case.  The former is nullable (and hence distinguishable from 0.0) and should be recognised by Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Having Double instead of double was helpful to me.